# How to programmatically terminate an NSDraggingSession?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

## Context:

- OS X Application implemented in Cocoa/ObjC
- Xcode 6.1
- Base SDK: 10.0
- Deployment Target: 10.8+

## Question:

In my app, I have a custom `NSView` subclass which implements `NSDraggingSource`. I'm using the new `NSDraggingSession`-based API (not the old deprecated one).

I have my dragging source fully implemented, no problems.

I am already implementing:

```
-[NSDraggingSource draggingSession:movedToPoint:]
```

I would like to additionally do some hit detection within this method and depending on the results of that hit test, possibly cancel the current drag session programmatically.

**So: What is the best way to cancel/terminate the current `NSDraggingSession` programmatically?** (preferably from `-[NSDraggingSource draggingSession:movedToPoint:]`)

It might be nice to also be able to specify the `NSDragOperation` upon termination too.

## Notes:

- I've tried calling `-[NSResponder cancelOperation:]` on my custom view, thinking this might have something to do with dragging sessions, but that doesn't work. I get an exception with ***unrecognized selector***.
- I **DO NOT** need help doing hit detection.
- I **DO NOT** need help implementing `NSDraggingSource` in general.

Comment: Hmmmm, a dragging session is usually ended, when the user lifts the mouse button. Doing that programmatically you could show him a terrifying image so the user releases the mouse button to hold his hands in front of his eyes. But how you can release the button programmatically? And what happens with the still pressed mouse button, when the dragging session has ended?

Comment: Yeah, after posting this question it finally dawned on me that Apple probably doesn't want you programmatically terminating a drag session, as it might be confusing to the user who hasn't released the mouse button. I think I'll leave this question here regardless… It might prove useful in some way, even if it's just to explain that this is not possible via public API.